# Функция сравнения символов в строке

Tags: python, функции

Необходимо чтобы функция:

```
1) Сравнивала первую букву со второй
2) После 1,2 буквы с 3,4 буквами
3) После 1,2,3 буквы с 4,6,6 буквами
```

И так далее до Длина строки // 2
Буду благодарен за пример кода.

Функция принимает строку произвольного размера, например abcabc
После чего сравнивает:

```
1 шаг
a и b
b и c
c и a
a и b
b и c

2 шаг
ab и ca
ca и bc


3 шаг
abc и abc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекурсивное решение (**UPD**):

```py
def func(string: str, k: int=1) -> None:
    length = len(string)
    if k > length // 2:
        return

    for i in range(0, length - k, k):
        part_1 = string[i:][:k]
        part_2 = string[i:][k:k*2]
        print(f'{part_1} и {part_2}')

    func(string, k+1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    func('abcabc')
```

*stdout:*

```html
a и b
b и c
c и a
a и b
b и c
ab и ca
ca и bc
abc и abc
```

Comment: Спасибо за обратную связь, однако мне нужно чтобы сравнивалось так: (по одному символу) H и e, e и l, l и l. После чего (по два символа) He и ll и после чего по 3 символа (или максимальная длина строки // 3) Hel и lo!

Comment: @CoffeeinTime Обновил ответ.

Comment: А можно как-то часть if recurse {
        getRepeats(String(p), index+1)
    } перетсавить до вызова рекурсии?

Comment: было бы идеально.

Comment: @CoffeeinTime Увидел Вашу правку. Но если так сделать, то порядок печати собьётся.

Comment: А возможно сохранить порядок печати? Но при этом, чтобы после рекурсивного вызова не было никаких условий. (Они у меня не сработают)

Comment: @CoffeeinTime Почему не сработают? У Вас какие-то искусственные ограничения.

Comment: Да, мне очень важно, чтобы после рекурсивного вызова ничего не было.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97110/discussion-between-nomnoms12-and-coffee-intime).